# aws cli --query doesn't filter output in windows command promt

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface

I am following the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/controlling-output.html#controlling-output-filter) to use the --query option in aws cli. However it doesn't work for me at all.  I have defined profiles because I have several accounts to pull the data.  If I omit the --query, it returns the data successfully. Any insight into this please?

Thank you

```
> aws --version
aws-cli/1.14.8 Python/3.6.3 Windows/10 botocore/1.8.12

> aws ec2 describe-volumes --profile TEST1 --region us-east-1 --query 'Volumes[0]'
"Volumes[0]"

> aws ec2 describe-volumes --profile TEST1 --region us-east-1
{
    "Volumes": [
        {
            "Attachments": [ ....
```

Answer (score 9):

Change from single quotes to double quotes:

```
aws ec2 describe-volumes --profile TEST1 --region us-east-1 --query "Volumes[0]"
```

Answer (score 0):

As soon as i switched to powershell, it works successfully.  Although I am not sure why it requires using powershell.

Comment: PowerShell accepts both single and double quotes. The vanilla command line does not. See https://superuser.com/questions/324278/how-to-make-windows-command-prompt-treat-single-quote-as-though-it-is-a-double-q.